# How to pass namedtuple key as a variable

Tags: python, namedtuple

I want to call different namedtuple values where my namedtuple key is passed from a variable.
Here I am trying to get the value of namedtuple qa where the key qa will be gotten from variable environment.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Credentials = namedtuple('Credentials',['name','password','ver'])
environment = "qa"
qa = Credentials('a','1','') 
qa_dev = Credentials('a','2','d') 
live = Credentials('b','c','') 
print ("The name using index is : ",end ="") 
print (live[0]) 
print ("The Student name using keyname is : ",end ="") 
print (qa.name)
**# Now I want to get the values by passing the environment variable as namedtuple key** 
print ((environment).name) 
print ((environment)[1])# this one prints the variable value char of the index
```

I am totally novice in python so my question might not be a good one.

Comment: Put your named tuples into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `eval` function to evaluate qa in your environment variable:

use below code after you define `qa`:

```
environment = eval(environment)
```